# Application of Stone-Weierstrass Theorem showing that this limit is $0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis

I'm given that $f$ is Riemann Integrable on $[a,b]$ and I want to show that there exist polynomials $P_n$ such that 
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int\limits_{a}^b |f(x)-P_n(x)|^2dx=0$$

I know I need to show that for every $\varepsilon>0$, there's a polynomial $P$ such that $$\int\limits_{a}^b |f(x)-P(x)|^2dx<\varepsilon$$ The problem is, I don't see how I can get the continuity condition to apply the Stone-Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: Re-write $f\left(x\right)$ as a power series...

Comment: @jm324354: Why is $f$ analytic?

Comment: By the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, this results reduces to showing that $f$ can be approximated by continuous functions with respect to the $L^2$ norm on $[a, b]$. To prove that, note that $f$ can be approximated by step functions, which can in turn have their jump discontinuities smoothed out to give continuous functions.

Comment: The point here is that $ f $ may not be continuous, so the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem cannot be applied directly.

Comment: @anomaly Is there a more direct approach? The one you describe is the hint given in Rudin, but I'm looking for another way.

Comment: @user5675443: If you specifically want to use the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, you're going to have to reduce from the case of integrable $f$ to continuous $f$. There are a lot of results saying that certain classes of functions are dense (in various norms) in the space of integrable functions, but I don't think there's anything a priori easier than dealing with step functions. The problem is that integrability is such a weak condition that it's difficult to proceed more directly.

Answer (score 1):

First, approximate $f$ by a step function $f_{S}$ such that
$$
                    \int_{a}^{b}|f-f_{S}|^{2}dx \le M\int_{a}^{b}|f-f_{S}|dx < \epsilon/3.
$$
This can be done by using the Riemann integrability of $f$, and the fact that a Riemann integrable function is uniformly bounded by some constant $K$. Then modify $f_{S}$ near the endpoints of the intervals where $f$ is constant to be linear in order to obtain a continuous function $f_{C}$ such that
$$
                  \int_{a}^{b}|f_{S}-f_{C}|dx < \epsilon/3.
$$
Finally, approximate $f_{C}$ by a polynomial $p$ in such a way that
$$
                 \int_{a}^{b}|f_{C}-p|dx < \epsilon/3.
$$

Comment: Possible typo error: “... near the endpoints of the intervals where $ \color{red}{f_{S}} $ is constant...”

Comment: Yes, $f_{S}$ is constant on each Riemann integral subdivision.